# Calculation FLOPs of adaptive_avg_pool2d

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I found several definitions of FLOPs in countering the flops for adaptive_avg_pool2d:

1. From [fvcore](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore/blob/master/fvcore/nn/flop_count.py#L40) , it defines the FLOPs as

```
1 * prod(input)
```

which is , `1 x N x C_in x H_in x W_in`.

2. Another definition is from the output perspective. I found one from [here](https://github.com/JJBOY/FLOPs/blob/master/FLOPs_counter.py#L73:9) :

It first calculate the kernel size, say, (kx, ky)

Then compute the flops as

```
( kx*xy +1 ) * prod(output)
```

which is , `(k_x x k_y + 1) x (N x C_out x H_out x W_out)`

Which definition is correct? Is there any material of calculating FLOPs?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841509/how-does-adaptive-pooling-in-pytorch-work) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869581/10886420) for how `torch.nn.Adaptive{Avg, Max}Pool{1, 2, 3}d` works.

Essentially, it tries to reduce overlapping of pooling kernels (which is not the case for `torch.nn.{Avg, Max}Pool{1, 2, 3}d`), **trying to go over each input element only once** (not sure if succeeding, but probably yes).

FLOPS refers to Floating Operations per Second, hence, if each input float value is "touched" (by max or mean per grouped parts of input) only once it would be equal to:

```
1 * prod(input)
```

To get FLOPS from this value you would have to divide that by the time it took to get through `1 * prod(input)` floating point operations.

Second formula seems correct for pooling, not the adaptive one.