# How to implement pytorch, adaptive_avg_pool2d in C++ own?

Tags: pytorch

I tried mimic the behavior of pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d, but I found the result not same:

```
def test_pool():
    a = np.fromfile("in.bin", dtype=np.float32)
    a = np.reshape(a, [1, 12, 25, 25])
    a = torch.as_tensor(a)

    b = F.adaptive_avg_pool2d(a, [7, 7])
    print(b)
    print(b.shape)

    avg_pool = torch.nn.AvgPool2d([7, 7], [3, 3])
    c = avg_pool(a)
    print(c)
    print(c.shape)
```

what is the principles behind pytorch adaptive_avg_pool2d?

Comment: It is pretty complex, check out existing answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63603993/6942666

Comment: I already figured it out, it's not compex and the answer you suggest are wrong. I posted myself under quesiton.