# PyTorch CNN Different Input Size

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, torch

Hello Guys I have a question about different Input Sizes.

My training set and validation dataset have an input Size of 256 and for my prediction (with an unseen Test Dataset) I have an input size of 496.

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, shape):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(shape,1,1)
        self.batch1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
        self.avgpl1 = nn.AvgPool1d(1, stride=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1,3)
    
    #forward method 
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.batch1(x)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.avgpl1(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x,1)
        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc1(x))
        return x
```

I saved the model and wanna use it also for my prediction.

**Error Message is:**

```py
Input In [244], in predict_data(prediction_data, model_path, data_config, context)
     25 new_model = Net(shape_preprocessed_data)
     26 # load the previously saved state_dict
---> 27 new_model.load_state_dict(torch.load("NetModel.pth"))
     29 # check if predictions of models are equal
     30 
     31 # generate random input of size (N,C,H,W)
     32 
     33 # switch to eval mode for both models
     34 model = model.eval()

    RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Net:
    size mismatch for conv1.weight: copying a param with shape 
    torch.Size([1, 256, 1]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1, 494, 1]).

How can I solve this?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reshape/downsample the input as the first step of the forward pass in your model. This can be done using the [`torch.nn.functional.interpolate`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html) function.

For example:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, shape):
    super(Net,self).__init__()
    self.input_shape = shape
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(shape,1,1)
    self.batch1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1)
    self.avgpl1 = nn.AvgPool1d(1, stride=1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1,3)

#forward method 
def forward(self,x):
    x = torch.nn.functional.interpolate(x, size=self.input_shape)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.batch1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = self.avgpl1(x)
    x = torch.flatten(x,1)
    x = F.log_softmax(self.fc1(x))
    return x
```

Your test images would then be downsampled to size 256 in order to be compatible with the model.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! Now i have this Error! 

"RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x256 and 1x3)"

I gave the Model a Input Size with 256. 

    shape_of_x_train = X_train.shape
    shape_of_x_train = shape_of_x_train[1]
    model = Net(shape_of_x_train)

BTW: They are no Images, they are sequential data --> shape (233, 256, 1)

Comment: This error suggests that your `fc1` linear layer is receiving an input of shape (128 x 256), but it is expecting something of shape (any x 1). This is because you initialized your linear layer as `nn.linear(1, 3)`. Either you have miscalculated the shapes of your input as it is manipulated by your model, or you should change your flatten layer from `torch.flatten(x, 1)` to `torch.flatten(x)`, which will flatten it to shape (32768 x 1), rather than (128 x 256).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool1d(output_size)` instead of `nn.AvgPool1d`, and mention the desired output size. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841509/how-does-adaptive-pooling-in-pytorch-work) for detailed explanation of how Adaptive average pooling works in Pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the saved model was initialized with `shape`, the number of input channels equal to `256`, while the model you are trying to load the weight onto `new_model` was initialized with `494`.

But this value refers to the feature size, not the sequence length. I believe you might have mixed up the two things. The feature size should remain constant. But in your case it's hard to say what you are trying to do since you are not providing information about the kind of dataset used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now it worked but now i have a another error message:`

TypeError: conv1d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (Test_Dataset, Parameter, Parameter, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)

What can i do for this Error?  Doesnt get it :D

Comment: What did you change in your code exactly?

Comment: I deleted the shape in the cnn --> than Model = Net() without the shape

Comment: Well, `Net` expects an argument, why would you remove it?